# Can't access extension's method in main

Tags: c#

I want to use extension's method 'esitaht' to print out the first letter of a word, but the debugger says that 'esitaht' does not exist in current context.

Extension:

```
using System;

namespace LaiendusMeetodid
{
    static class TekstiMeetodid
    {
        public static string esitaht(string s)
        {
            var t2ht = s.Split()[0];
            return t2ht;
        }
    }
}
```

Main

```
using System;
using LaiendusMeetodid;

public class main
{
    public static void Main(string[] arg)
    {
        var test = esitaht("Test");
    }
}
```

Comment: You should use code *TekstiMeetodid.esitaht("Test")* to call static method.

Comment: `esitaht` is not an extension method - if it were, you would use it like a class method such as `"Test".esitaht()`. Since it is not an extension method, you must call it like `TekstiMeetodid.esitaht("Test")`.

Comment: Extension method uses the "this" keyword as the first parameter with a type in .Net and this method will called by a given type instance on the client side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You defined a static method and used it without referencing where it came from.
You either need to `using static LaiendusMeetodid;`, `LaiendusMeetodid.esitaht("Test");`
or use the `this` constraint

```cs
public static string esitaht ( this string s ){
    var t2ht = s.Split()[0];
    return t2ht;
}
```

and `"Test".esitaht()`